# How do I slowly transition the color of an infinitely-color-changing text into one solid color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Hello good folks of stackoverflow,

I cannot, for the life of me, wrap my head around this. How can I can slowly transition this color-changing text from it's current color into any other solid color (upon clicking the submit button). Is there any pro here that can solve this "puzzle"? It would honestly be extremely appreciated.

Example code:

```js
jQuery('.text').html(function(i, html) {
  var chars = jQuery.trim(html).split("");
  return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});

jQuery('#submitbutton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('submitting');
  }, 2000);
  document.querySelector('#textdisplay > span').classList.remove('anim');
  document.getElementById("textdisplay").style.color = "yellow";
});
```

```css
#textdisplay span.anim {
  -webkit-animation-name: color-text-flow-keys;
  animation-name: color-text-flow-keys;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 50s;
  animation-duration: 50s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes color-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #d65c97;
  }
  25% {
    color: #5cd666;
  }
  50% {
    color: #d67e5c;
  }
  100% {
    color: #64d65c;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
        <button type="submit" id="submitbutton">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
      <div id='textdisplay'>
        <span class="anim">BlueBox</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code in jquery for tarnsition with 2s

```
  document.getElementById("textdisplay").style.transition = "2s";
```

i think this will help you

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input! Where exactly do I place this and how come this would work, though?

Comment: place the  code above the second last line of code in jquery. Using transition  it allows you to change property values smoothly, over a given duration. i.e 2s